# Can I add own commands to the CLI?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, command-line-interface, nestjs

Is it possible to add own commands to the CLI to scaffold own architecture components?

So what I would like to do is to scaffold an own component with an own command, e.g. like `nest generate MyOwnArchitectureComponent componentOne`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not yet possible with the nest CLI. There is an [open Github issue](https://github.com/nestjs/nest-cli/issues/99) by the nest members though and it is part of the backlog so it will probably be implemented at some point. Follow this issue and/or add your ideas to the [discussion](https://github.com/nestjs/nest-cli/issues/187).